# how to pass props down to createUseStyles in react JSS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jss

I'm building a tooltip for a storybook. I'm fairly new to JSS. I wish to set color AND background color via props, I named textColor to change the text's color and color to change the background:

```
interface ITooltipProps {
direction: string;
color: string;
textColor: string;
delay?: number;
children: ReactElement;
content: ReactNode
}



const Tooltip = (props: ITooltipProps): ReactElement | null => {
const {direction, color, textColor} = props;

let timeout: NodeJS.Timeout;
const theme = useTheme();
const classes = useStyles(props);
...
```

However it seems that it only works for one property in the props at a time, as soon as I try to introduce A second property, typescript yells that textColor does not exist:

```
const useStyles = createUseStyles(() => ({
 tooltipWrapper: {
 display: 'inline-block',
 position: 'relative'
 },
 tooltipTip: {
  position: 'absolute',
  borderRadius: '4px',
  left: '50%',
  transform: 'translateX(-50%)',
  padding: '6px',
  color: (props) => props.textColor || '',  <-- Property 'textColor' does not exist on type '{ 
  color: string; }'

  background: (props) => props.color || '',   <-- works fine
```

The only way I can make it work is by explicitly set the type to have both properties in one of the anonymous functions:

```
color: (props) => props.textColor || '',  <--- works fine
background: (props: {color: string, textColor: string}) => props.color || '', <--- works fine
```

Would be greatly appreciated to know whats going on, and if I can only grab one property at a time like in the exaple that does not work. Thank you

link to github repo: https://github.com/luki2000/tooltip

Not sure if its the cleanest solution but by explicity passing the interface it worked:

ANSWER:

```
color: (props: ITooltipProps) => props.textColor || '',
background: (props: ITooltipProps) => props.color || '',
```

I could be wrong but this is what I think was happening before. When we set the first anonymous function in the createUseStyles without a type on the parameter, the type was inferred from the what we try to return which only contained one property 'color'. This also meant that any other anonymous function had to follow what was inferred so when I attemped to do props.textColor it said 'Hold on there is only property color what are you doing!'.